# Equivalence of two separate data distribution

Tags: classification, statistics, data, similarity

I am working in generative modelling. I have a real dataset of which I want to know the underlying distribution. For this I create a synthetic data generator which tries to mimic the real data. I train a classifier on one part of the real dataset. Then I test on the artificial data as well as the testset from the real data.

If my specified model is predicting equally well (say in terms of classification accuracy) on two unrelated datasets; can I assume/conclude that the two datasets follow the same distribution? The parameters of the predictive model remain **exactly the same** in both the cases.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to the forum. I guess you need to provide more details here...

Comment: I am working in generative modelling. I have a real dataset of which I want to know the underlying distribution. For this I create a synthetic data generator which tries to mimic the real data. I train a classifier on one part of the real dataset. Then I test on the artificial data as well as the testset from the real data. Now the above question follows! Thanks for your time.

Comment: @anildadj I added your explanation given as comment to the question, feel free to edit back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If my specified model is predicting equally well (say in terms of classification accuracy) on two unrelated datasets; can I assume/conclude that the two datasets follow the same distribution? The parameters of the predictive model remain exactly the same in both the cases.

No you cannot, because there is no general equivalence between the two datasets having the same distribution and their performance being identical. There is only a one-way implication: **if** the two datasets have the same distribution, **then** their performance is identical.

There are actually many ways in which the datasets could have the same performance without following the same distribution, for instance if the design of the model doesn't properly represent the data, or simply by chance.

So the exact same performance is only **compatible with the hypothesis** that the datasets have the same distribution, but it doesn't prove it.

As far as I know, proving that two datasets have the same distribution with a complex set of features is a difficult problem. Additionally if the original dataset is small it's difficult to know how representative it is of the true distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: An added thought if could please explain! If my generated data is helping better prediction in the test data, can I comment/conclude the data generated now follows the training data distribution?

Comment: @anildadj do you mean that when you add the generated data to the original data in the training set, this leads to better predictions in the test set? Anyway unfortunately that still wouldn't prove same distribution, but this could certainly prove a strong benefit of the generated data

Comment: Yes I meant that. Though it only happens by chance being 1 out of 20 times. The worst case scenario is that prediction accuracy after training on the generated data is never less than that when trained on real data. Please comment on this.

Comment: The test set is made only of original data right? Ok so this is a strong indication that the generated data has a similar distribution as the original data. In my opinion proving better (or at least as good) performance is actually more useful than proving identical distribution.

Comment: Yes the test set is made up of only original data. I had one more development. When I trained several classifiers like SVM, NN, Naive Bayes etc. I found 7 out of 9 deteriorated in accuracy barring SVM and its variant, which could reach an accuracy of 96%. I do not know how to interpret/explain this in a research article. Can you please help and guide me as to how do I come up with a proof of this. My background is not CS, that's why asking. Thanks.

Comment: @anildadj you mean that the accuracy decreases between training on the original data and training on the generated data right? It's difficult to reach any clear conclusion from that (especially without knowing any of the details), but it's an indication in the opposite direction. I don't think there's anything to prove here, it's experimental so you should just report precisely the methodology and all the results including the negative ones. Ideally if you can find an explanation (or an hypothesis) for why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, that would add value to your work.